# How to move to another activity without finishing it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I have a dashboard activity which has a settings button, once clicked it will proceed to the settings activity without finishing the dashboard activity. In my settings activity, there is a switch which plays a music when checked and stops the music when unchecked. There is also a back button which directs the user back to the dashboard, once clicked it will just finish the settings activity. However, in a situation where I check the switch, the music plays then I click the back button, I'm directed to the dashboard activity but the music still plays in the background. However, if I try to click the settings button again to go back to the settings activity, the switch is unchecked but the music is playing. What i wanted to happen is that, how can i go back to dashboard activity by pressing the back button without finishing settings activity so that the status of the switch is still checked whenever I click the settings button again from the dashboard activity to go to the settings activity.

Dashboard Activity

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;

    switch(v.getId())
    {
       case R.id.settings_card:
            i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
```

Settings Activity

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Switch component on settings activity

```
playstop.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked == true)
            {
                startService(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ApplicationService.class));
            }
            else
            {
                stopService(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ApplicationService.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your architecture is a good one as you are saving state in the individual activities. However, you should be able to get what you want by simply flipping back and forth betwen your 2 activities. To do this, you need to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` when you launch an `Activity`:

```
i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

This will bring the existing instance of the target `Activity` to the front instead of creating a new instance. You can keep flipping between your 2 activities this way without finishing.

Comment: I am glad you were able to solve your problem! If this answer was helpful you can accept it by clciking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will also get the question off the list of open questions.

Answer (score 0):

For things like settings that should be saved in your app even when users close it and open again it is good to use [SharedPreferenes](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). You can save the state of your "check button" in SharedPreferences and later load it on the onResume method in your SettingsActivity. This solution will save the state of your settings switch even users close the whole app.

Another solution is to use Bundle and onSavedInstance():
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#instance-state

But it will not working if you want to save settings even when user closes the whole app.

Comment: I'm afraid the second solution you suggested may not work because when I start dashboard activity again and click settings button to go to settings activity again, it will just open another settings activity and will not save the settings I made before.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question btw

Comment: Ok, have checked it, you are right. So you can try do restore state of the SettingsActivity by Bundle and onSaveInstanceState()https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras But I think that the best will be to use SharedPreferences. I have edited my previous answer :)